# Omniauth, Devise, Facebook integration guide not working

Tags: facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, devise, omniauth

I started up a completely new Rails and Facebook app and followed this [guide](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth%3a-Overview) to the letter.

I can see that a user is getting created and that it even becomes the current_user for the redirect after authentication, however, it doesn't persist. As soon as I hit another controller action, it once again redirects and says I need to sign in.

I'd post my code if I thought any of it would be useful but the only differences between mine and what you see in this wiki ( https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth%3a-Overview ) are the puts statements in before filters and methods.

I'm not 100% sure how devise with omniauthable works but I do notice that in its `self.find_for_facebook_oauth` method, it takes in current_user as the 2nd argument and never uses it in the method. In addition, unlike other auth solutions, I don't see it checking for an existing user session anywhere though I believe devise is supposed to take care of this for you.

## Edit

I'm now pretty sure there is something incredibly wrong with `omniauthable`. I just added the following to my `OmniauthCallbacksController`

```
def facebook
  sign_in_and_redirect :user, User.first
end
```

Essentially this should just login the first user regardless of information. It does and redirects me to a page in my Welcome controller, however, when I try and hit the other action in that controller, I get told once again that I need to sign in. I really have no idea how the current_user is getting lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are very few resources on how to use Devise's omniauthable module. You might want to have a look at https://gist.github.com/993566 and http://edmiston.id.au/post/9204306833/omniauthable-my-version . The wiki is missing a few details.

Comment: I checked out both of these posts and didn't find anything different that I could use to get Facebook authentication working. I updated my post to include the last ditch effort that shows me something must be wrong with devise's omniauthable.

Comment: If the code is not confidential please upload the project on github, I would like to play around and see if I can zero in on the problem.

Comment: I had a look and its working fine. I copied the facebook strategy for github as I deactivated my facebook account long time back. There does not seem to be any problem. I created a new controller Home#index and copied the contents of welcome#index view to home#index. I logged in via github and was redirected to welcome#index. Then I pointed my browser to /home/index and I was once again presented with my session data. I am sorry can't figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Does Home have `before_filter :authenticate_user!` ?

Comment: My apologies for the delay. I will deploy the app once again and report the results by tomorrow.

Comment: @Aaron The repository no longer exists on github. If you have figured out the solution on your own please post the answer.

Comment: Ah! Sorry about that. I was doing some cleaning of digital and non digital life over the holiday and accidentally got that one. Thanks for your help with this btw.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry i cant answer your question, but maybe you schould check out http://railscasts.com/ , there are few great video tutoriales for facebook integration.

Comment: If they're the videos I'm thinking of, they were made before Devise had it's `:omniauthable` option. I may just use another solution since I don't need all of Devise's functionality but I'm dying to know why Devise's own walk through isn't working.